# SQL Server Express folder permissions

Tags: permissions, ssms

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to interact with a SQL Server Express instance. I want to attach a database (.mdf file) that is located in my documents folder `C:\User\ME\documents\foo`. Unfortunately the file browser that Server Management Studio gives me cannot access my documents folder due to permissions issues.

I don't want to solve this problem by adding 'everyone' to the list of users allowed access, so what user can I add so that Management Studio can access the `.mdf` file in `documents\foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow access to the account that the sql server instance server is running as. (Check in services.cpl)
If it's running as one of the BuiltIns, you might not want to give it access to MyDocuments.
If you create a specific account to run sql server under make sure you give it all the relevant permissions, otherwise it you'll break it.

Personally I'd save my self a lot of pain and just move it in to some folder "you" and the built in account can see.

Comment: It's important to note that when you use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to attach the DB then the ssms needs to have permissions to the folder with the DB as well. Or you can just run the ssms as administrator using "Run as Administrator".