# Where are my Local SQL Server Express Database Files?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, sql-server-express

I read that my Local SQL Server Express Database Files should be located here (since user on my machine is "bclay"):

> C:\Users\bclay\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local
> DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB

...but that can't be, as the newest file there is over 2 months old, and I updated SQL Server Express data today (via my C# Winforms app, created with Visual Studio 2019). How can I sleuth out where those files are, so I can back them up?

### UPDATE

Using the answer from marc_s, I was able to get that from Visual Studio's Server Explorer:

[image]

### UPDATE 2

Okay, this seems bizarre: I navigate to that location in Windows Explorer, and it won't show me what's in the \Data subfolder. Although I have selected the Data subfolder, it is showing me what's in the Installs subfolder below it, and when I right-click the Data subfolder to czech out its properties, it tells me I don't have the credentials to view it:

[image]

How can I backup the .mdf file if I can't even see it?

### UPDATE 3

I did a hard-drive-wide search for all *.mdf files, and it does not "find" (show me) my tables. The only ones that could be related are the top ones here, but they have generic names:

[image]

### UPDATE 4

I think it was marc_s that mentioned somewhere to use MS SQL Server Management Studio, and to select Task > Backup. I downloaded/installed it, and it seemed to work: it did create a Backup folder in the expected location. I see that it was created today, 10/1/2020, but I still can't see anything in the folder, thus I can't copy anything from it. Here's what I see (the contents of the last-selected folder) when I select the "Backup" folder:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SSMS, if you're connected to the database in question, you can run this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.database_files
```

and the `physical_name` column in the result set will show you the path of the files in question

Comment: It's true that's where they are, but Windows Explorer won't let me view them for some reason.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: why would you need to? You should let SQL Server deal with the details of handling the files - you just talk to and work with SQL Server ...

Comment: This is a local database; I want to store the tables on a usb stick or on OneDrive so that I have a backup if necessary

Comment: I think it was marc_s that mentioned somewhere to use Server Management Studio, and to select Task > Backup. This seemed to work: it did create a Backup folder in the expected location. But I still can't see anything in it. See Update 4.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: when you run `Tasks > Backup`, you should be able to pick the target directory, and SQL Server should create a `.bak` file there for you that you can copy around - to external devices, USB sticks etc. You cannot directly see what's inside that `.bak` file - but you *can* to a `RESTORE` on another (or the same) SQL Server and get back the whole database from that `.bak` file

Comment: Perfect, I changed it to a newly-created folder, backed it up there, then from there to a usb stick.

Answer (score 0):

As @marc_s said, since you've found where are located the MDB file, just copy them on your USB stick and you are done.

Comment: How can I when Windows Explorer doesn't let me see the contents of the folder?

Comment: In you're UPDATE 2 picture can you access the "advance" button and add your windows account with read permissions? This look like this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448894/sql-server-express-folder-permissions

Comment: The first time I look at the Data folder it shows me *.mdf and *.ldf files, and the "Advanced" button shows "Readonly" semi-checked and "Hidden" unchecked. If I go away from there by clicking another subfolder, and then go back, it won't show me the contents of Data anymore. This isn't the right location anyway, though, because the *.mdf/*.ldf files are not the ones I'm looking to back up - I can tell this both from their filenames and their dates.